# joomla/php - add another templete file to com_search component

Tags: php, templates, joomla

Is possible add my own template(s) into joomla search component and call it by link?

> example: /search?......searchphrase.....template=MYOWN

I did not mean template override. I obviously use this option.
it is more about knowing how to separate the search results because they are very extensive and I want to keep it clear.
I have created my own search plugin to search in my tables outside of joomla (the same database). I'm saving the search phrase in a session, and now I'm always able to call it with another template. I will divide the results and search this way. My tables in DB have 45mil. records.
in practice, I will be browsing another table with another template. This will increase speed and also remain user-friendly.
and it is best to call the template via the link in the menu (left menu -> every item, own template, own tables to search)